# How to save a data array object to ionic SQlite storage (TypeScript, Angular 5, Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular5

I'm trying to save a data array object with many attributes to a favorite list using Ionic SQlite storage.

For instance, I have a data array in data provider:

**data.ts**

```
     private options: any[] = [

        {
          "name": "option 01",
          "website": "www.google.com",
          "about": "choose this option 01",
          "id": "1"
        },

        {
          "name": "option 02",
          "website": "www.yahoo.com",
          "about": "choose this option 02",
          "id": "2"
        },
        {
          "name": "option 03",
          "website": "www.bing.com",
          "about": "choose this option 03",
          "id": "3"
        },
        {
          "name": "option 04",
          "website": "www.stackoverflow.com",
          "about": "choose this option 04",
          "id": "4"
        }
    ]
```

and I'm calling these data objects in my **home html** page which has an option to save to favorite list.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let option of options">
  <h1>{{option.name}}</h1>
  <h1>{{option.about }}</h1>
<h4>{{option.website}}</h4>

<button ion-button block (click)="saveToFavorite()">Save to Favorite List</button>

<button ion-button block (click)="removeFromFavorite()">Remove from Favorite List</button>
</ion-card>
```

and here's incomplete **home.ts** file

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

const STORAGE_KEY = 'favoriteOptions';

  saveToFavorite(option) {

    this.storage.set();
  }

  removeFromFavorite(option) {
   this.storage.remove();
  }
```

I want saveToFavorite() will save option data array object to a favorite options storage key so I can load them all up on a **favoriteList HTML** page:

```
<ion-content>
    <div *ngFor="let option of options">
        <h1>{{option.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{option.about}}</p>
        <button ion-button block (click)="removeFromFavorite()">Remove from Favorite List</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**favoriteList ts** file:

```
  getAllFavoriteOptions() {
    return this.storage.get(STORAGE_KEY);
  }

  removeFromFavorite(option) {
   this.storage.remove();
  }
```

Somehow I'm kinda lost. Please correct my codes on ts files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: <button ion-button block (click)="saveToFavorite(option)">Save to Favorite List</button> 

For removing as well.

Comment: Thanks, I want to know how to save several data array objects to sqlite storage..  I can manage to save just one but whenever I try to save others, it overrides the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a function to save the favorites:

```
addFavorite(favorite:any):void{
  let favorites = this.storage.get('favorites');
  if(favorites){
    favorites.push(favorite);
    this.storage.set('favorites', favorites);
  }else{
    favorites = [];
    favorites.push(favorite);
    this.storage.set('favorites',favorites);
  }
```

then to get favorites add this function:

```
getFavorites():any{
  let favorites = this.storage.get("favorites");
  return favorites;
}
```

**for ionic**: if you are using `@ionic/storage` then to load items use [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe):

```
getFavorites():Promise<any>{
  let favorites = this.storage.get("favorites");
  return favorites;
}
```

then to access them in *ngFor  do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of getFavorites() | async">
      <div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```