# How to fetch data using *ngFor directive from storage on Ionic 3 (Cordova, Ionic 3, Angular 5)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic's storage to save javascript data object which has several attributes. I'm trying to create a favorite list which can fetch data from ionic storage.

Here's my data **provider TS** file.

```
  private items: any[] = [

    {
   "name": "item 01",
   "description": "this is item 01",
   "id": "1"
   },
    {
   "name": "item 02",
   "description": "this is item 02",
   "id": "2"
   },
    {
   "name": "item 03",
   "description": "this is item 03",
   "id": "3"
   },
   {
"name": "item 04",
 "description":"this is item 04",
 "id":"4"
 }
]
```

and I'm saving items on my html file using a button. 
the main HTML file is using *ngFor let of directive to fetch the items from the provider.

**Main HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items"> 
  <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>  
  <p>{{item.description}}</p>
  <button (click)="saveToFav(item)">Save to favorites</button>
</div>
```

**Main TS file:**

```
savToFav(item) {
this.storage.set(this.item.id, this.item);
}
```

This saves the item with its attributes to Ionic storage. I can see that showing up on my browser's inspect -> application page.

and I'm trying to fetch items from ionic storage to a favorite HTML page.

**Favorite HTML page:**

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of items"> 
      <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>  
      <p>{{item.description}}</p>
      <button (click)="remove(item)">Remove from favorites</button>
    </div>
```

**Favorite TS file**

```
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.storage.get(this.item);
});
```

But this really doesn't load anything on favorite html page..

What should I do to fetch every item stored in Ionic storage to favorite HTML page?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49966216/9613505

Comment: @Hussein if OP is using [ionic storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) then data set and get return promises. You might want to fix your answer

Comment: @Hussein, thanks for your answer.. but this question is a little different. I'm trying to fetch all items. Now I can save items using example above but am trying to fetch all items from ionic storage and call them up using *ngFor directive.

Comment: can you show me the component where it load the items ?

Comment: I'm using a data provider which has a data object array. and there's favorite HTML page which should load saved items from ionic storage... but this doesn't work well with *ngFor. I'm looking for the easiest solution.

Comment: i've updated my answer, try it & lemme know

Comment: I will try now. thanks!

Comment: @Hussein, it doesn't work. The whole app freezes. Can you check if you're missing codes for Async Pipe?

Comment: it should now, my mistake sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a data array object to ionic SQlite storage (TypeScript, Angular 5, Ionic 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961425/how-to-save-a-data-array-object-to-ionic-sqlite-storage-typescript-angular-5)

Comment: No it isn't a duplicate. I'm still looking for answers.. the answer didn't work. Let me know if there's any better solution. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using storage get and set function in wrong manner, All the favorite items must be stored in the single key so that later when required you can have all the list of the favorites. It should be like the below one

```
savToFav(item) {
  this.storage.get('favoritesList')
  .then((fav)=>{
    if(fav == null){
       fav = [];
    }
    //This will fetch the old items and push the new item in array
    fav.push(item); return fav;
  })
  .then((fav)=>{
    //this will store the new update favorite list array in storage.
    this.storage.set('favoritesList',fav);
  })
}

//Favorite ts file you can use it like below 
this.storage.get('favoritesList').then((fav)=>{
 //you can asssing it any variable and use in your *ngFor loop
  this.myFavList = fav;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! how would you assign it to a variable in this.storage.get('favoritesList').then((fav)=>{ })  ? I'm trying this now.

Comment: and "push" throws an error message. It says 'Cannot read property 'push' of null TypeScript errror'

Comment: You can add a check for such case

Comment: @jamesharvey i have edited answer to add check for null

Comment: Thanks! I solved this problem by using interface and array!