# How do I store multiple items in local storage?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am making a map using the Leaflet.js library. I have an event that places a marker on the map on right click, and I want to save the coordinates from each marker to an array or an array of objects. I then want to store them in local storage.

```
var customLayer = new L.layerGroup();
myMap.on('contextmenu', function(e) {

  var marker = L.marker(e.latlng,
  {icon : flagIcon,
    draggable: true,
    zIndexOffset : 1000}).addTo(customLayer).addTo(myMap);
    customLayer.addTo(myMap);
  marker.bindPopup("<b>Custom</b>").openPopup();
  });
```

I did try setting values in local storage, but it only saved the first key: value pair. I then thought about iterating over the array that the customMarkers are stored in, but I get an error that customLayer.forEach is not a function.

```
  customLayer.forEach(function(marker) {
  var customCoords = marker.getLatLng();
  console.log(customCoords);

  });
```

I'd be very grateful for a hint, here. In case anyone wants it, here is the leaflet documentation:

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html

As with my last question about Leaflet, I did extensive research of 20 queries or more, but I did not find any answers to my question. I admit that it is possible I was asking the wrong questions. If so, please enlighten me.

**EDIT**
I used this inside my event function, but it only saves the value of the last item placed.

```
  myStorage = window.localStorage;
  mystorage.setItem('coords', e.latlng);
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried the below based on one of the answers, but nothing happened.

```
var layers = customLayer.getLayers();
var i;
for(i=0; i<layers.length; i++){
  layers[i];//it is what a super class for marker.
 //store them away
 myStorage = window.localStorage;
 myStorage.setItem('coords', layers[i].getLatLng());
}
```

});

**EDIT 3**

```
  function setJSON(customCoords, coordinates) {
    customCoords = 'customCoords';
      window.localStorage.setItem(customCoords, 
JSON.stringify(coordinates));
  }
```

});

I tried the above code from one of the answers below, and localStorage just output undefined. I tried passing the strings as parameters, but that gave me unexpected string errors. I then changed the parameter to a variable and assigned the string to it, and it still didn't work. However, I found a solution to the issue, and I posted it below.

Comment: show me the part where you tried to save to local storage..

Comment: Edited for you near the bottom.

Comment: so you are struggling with looping on LayerGroup then, did you try customLayer.getLayer().forEach()?

Comment: try using `eachLayer` method https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#layergroup-eachlayer

Comment: regarding the issue of saving multiple `coords`, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49966216/9613505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// on page load
var coordinates = [];

// in the event function
coordinates.push(e.latlng);
```

You should then be able to store it as stringified JSON. Consider using helper functions, something like:

```
function setJSON(key, value) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}
function getJSON(key) {
    return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
}
```

Then store the array

```
setJSON('clickedPoints', coordinates);
```

Later you can retrieve it like this

```
getJSON('clickedPoints');
```

Comment: Ok, but how does that work with my example storing multiple key value pairs? I don't know the values in advance, so how do I get them from customLayer?

Comment: You have two questions in one post. My answer only addresses how you can store object (key/value pairs). By doing: setJSON('customCoords',customCoords) then for retrieving getJSON('customCoords')

Comment: Kind sir, if you read my whole question, you would know that my loop did not work. Asking multiple questions and asking complicated ones are separate circumstances. Thank you for taking the time to respond

Comment: I understand, now, that I worded this question poorly. I should have asked how to add to local storage from a loop. You were actually right about it being multiple questions, I suppose. The first is how do I get the coordinates out of the customLayer array. The second is how do you setItem to local storage from a loop. Since your answer is supposed to answer part two, can you give more explanation to your answer? Are the key and value "coords" and "coordinates[i]" ?

Comment: Updated answer. JSON.stringify allows you to store non-primitive values like in your case an array in local storage so there is no need for a loop. You did good research, sorry if being harsch before. Good luck!

Comment: I tried your answer, and it caused an unexpected string error. Then, I tried assigning the string to a variable and using that as the parameter, but nothing happened. I found a solution, but I would still like to know yours.

Comment: Lol. For some reason, I thought you were telling me to place those in the parameters on creation instead of on call. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to read the documentation and help out here...it appears you know how to use `LocalStorage`, but trying to figure out how to loop LayerGroups. And there seem to be more than one way.

did you try?:

```
var layers = customLayer.getLayers();
var i;
for(i=0; i<layers.length; i++){
  layers[i];//it is what a super class for marker.
 //store them away
}
```

Also, there is

```
group.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer;//use layer to get what you want.
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me where in the documentation led you to these conclusions?

Comment: I updated my answer with one of the methods. I know it must be wrong, but it looks to me like it should work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the event portion of one of the answers above, I made a forEach for the array containing the coordinates, and I used the localStorage.setItem method with the coordinates as the parameter. The code is below:

```
var coordinates = [];
var customLayer = new L.layerGroup();
myMap.on('contextmenu', function(e) {
  var marker = L.marker(e.latlng,
  {icon : flagIcon, draggable: true, zIndexOffset : 
1000}).addTo(customLayer).addTo(myMap);
  marker.bindPopup("<b>Custom</b>").openPopup();
  customLayer.addTo(myMap);
  coordinates.push(e.latlng);
  console.log(coordinates);

  coordinates.forEach(function() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('customCoords', 
JSON.stringify(coordinates));

  });
```

This stored the coordinates in an array of objects with customCoords as the key in localStorage.

**EDIT**

I was confused on how to use Anders' answer, but he straightened it out for me. My answer works, but his is more elegant.